# g++ unable to link static version of shared objects

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

I want to hide as much information as I can from `ldd`, so I'm learning how to statically link in libraries instead of dynamically linking them. I've read from another stackoverflow post that the correct syntax is

```
g++ -ldynamiclib -o exe files.cpp staticlib.a
```

Thus, my current compilation code looks like this:

```
STATIC_LIB=""
STATIC_LIB="$STATIC_LIB ${PATH}/libcrypto.a"
STATIC_LIB="$STATIC_LIB ${PATH}/libdl-2.5.so" // I couldn't find the .a version for this, so I tried doing it this way, and have also tried doing just -ldl
STATIC_LIB="$STATIC_LIB ${PATH}/libstdc++.a"
STATIC_LIB="$STATIC_LIB ${PATH}/libgcc.a"
STATIC_LIB="$STATIC_LIB ${PATH}/libc.a"

g++ -g -I${INCLUDE_PATH} -o executable file1.cpp file2.cpp $STATIC_LIB
```

I've confirmed with `ldd` that this way works for libcrypto, as it is an external library that I brought in. However, this does not work at all for everything else, and I can still see them being listed when I use `ldd`. Does anyone knows the correct way of doing this?

P.S. I've also tried several other alternatives such as including -static, or using -Wl,-Bstatic, and I couldn't get either of those to work. Not sure if it's my syntax or if it's just not possible.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious about the need to `hide as much information as I can from ldd`. Maybe XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: It's just a step in analyzing the executable for extra information on how to break the program. Reverse engineering. Assuming that someone is trying to break the program or get information from it, I just wanted to hide as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Those libraries `libstdc++`, `libgcc` and `libc` are special in that they're very fundamental to the running of any program compiled with `gcc`. Special `gcc` options exist if you want to link them statically, namely `-static-libstdc++` and `-static-libgcc`.

Note that you should really know what you're doing if you choose these options. It can create portability problems for your program, many of which express themselves in unintuitive ways.

Comment: I've tried those two options before, but the compiler I'm using is quite old and do not have `-static-libstdc++`. And when I added `-static-libgcc`, I was still able to see it when I perform `ldd`.